# Return an empty string array in a vba function

Tags: arrays, vba

My code will not compile because of mismatch between return array and function return:

```
Function getRowFrom2DArray(Arr As Variant, RowNumber As Long) As String()
If NumberOfArrayDimensions(Arr) <> 2 Then
        getColumnFrom2DArray = Array()
        Exit Function
    End If
```

How can I force `= Array()` to be of type string, can I use the split function? `split("","")` or whats the best way?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is your intention but your function is named getRowFrom2DArray and you are using getColumnFrom2DArray within your condition?

Answer (score 1):

It is a long time ago that I've workt with VBA but as far as I remember you can use `ReDim getRowFrom2DArray(0)` to initialize an empty array.